# Turn Based Game in unity C# in android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good Day! I have this code but I have an error, for example (I set two players me, and 1 computer). I take the first turn, and the dice respawn with a value of 4 (just an example), the game piece then move from 1st to 4th tile when I touch the screen, when computer turns, it also move from 1st to 4th tile (because I set the result to 4 just an example). Now its my turn again, the dice never respawn and it doesn't wait to touch the screen `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` and move again by 4...

```
public class singlePlay : MonoBehaviour {
    //Player 
    public GameObject[] playerprefab;

    //Player Clone
    public GameObject[] playerprefabC;

    //Game Cards and Dice
    public GameObject[] situationCard;
    public GameObject dice;
    int diceresult;

    //Game Cards and Dice clone
    public GameObject diceclone;

    public int currentPlayer;
    public int compPlayer;
    public int playerTurn;
    public string compPlayerstring;
    public string playerTurnstring;

    //GUI Boolean
    bool play = false;

    //Game Boolean
    bool pieces = false;
    bool giveturn = false;
    bool myturn = false;
    bool diceSpawn = false;
    bool moving = false;
    bool routine = false;
    bool checking = false;  
    bool compturn = false;
    //icon1
    public GameObject[] icon;

    //population
    int[] population = new int[3];

    //Tile
    public GameObject[] Tile;
    int[] playerTile = new int[3]; //current location
    int[] playerTileUp = new int [3]; // updated location after dice roll

    bool endTurn = false;

    void Update () 
    {
        if (giveturn == true) {
            int h = 0;
            Giveturn(h);
            giveturn = false;
        }

        if (play == true) {

            if (pieces == true){
                SpawnPlayer();
                pieces = false;
            }

            if (myturn == true){
                compturn = false;
                if(diceSpawn == true) {
                    dice.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,-1);
                    diceclone = Instantiate(dice, dice.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    diceSpawn = false;
                }
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    Debug.Log("click");
                    diceresult = 4;
                    Destroy(diceclone);
                    moving = true;
                    Updateposition(diceresult);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("comp");
                myturn = false;
                diceresult = 4;
                moving = true;
                Updateposition(diceresult);
            }
        }
    }

    void Giveturn(int k) 
    {
        Debug.Log("" + k);
        currentPlayer = k;
        if (k == playerTurn) {
            Debug.Log("Yes");
            compturn = false;
            myturn = true;
            diceSpawn = true;
            moving = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("No");
            compturn = true;
            myturn = false;
            moving = false;
        }
    }

    void Updateposition(int diceresult) 
    {
        if (moving == true) {
            playerTileUp[currentPlayer] = playerTile[currentPlayer] + diceresult;
            Debug.Log("" + playerTileUp[currentPlayer]+ " " +currentPlayer);
            routine = true;
            StartCoroutine(MyMethod()); 
        }
        moving = false;
    }

    IEnumerator MyMethod() 
    {
        if (routine == true) {
            if (myturn == true) {
                compturn = false;
            }
            else
            {
                myturn = false;
            }

            int f = playerTile[currentPlayer] + 1;
            Debug.Log(" " + currentPlayer );

            while (f <= playerTileUp[currentPlayer]) {
                Debug.Log("waiting");
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
                Debug.Log(" " + Tile[f]);
                playerprefabC[currentPlayer].transform.position =  Tile[f].transform.position;
                Debug.Log(" " + currentPlayer);
                f++;
            }
            checking = true;
            TrapCheck();
        }
        routine = false;
    }

    void TrapCheck()
    {
        if (checking == true) {
            if (playerTileUp[currentPlayer] == 8) {
                Debug.Log("Trap spawning");
                Instantiate(situationCard[0], situationCard[0].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                population[currentPlayer] = population[currentPlayer] -1;
            }

            playerTile[currentPlayer] = playerTileUp[currentPlayer];
            Endturn();
            myturn = false;
            compturn = false;
            checking = false;
        }
    }

    void Endturn()
    {
        currentPlayer++;
        Debug.Log(" " + currentPlayer);
        if (currentPlayer > compPlayer) {
            currentPlayer = 0;
        }
        Giveturn(currentPlayer);
    }   
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of variables that are initialized outside of this scope of code. You should probably include them in your code to help answer your question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Aron When it comes to my turn (2nd turn) after the computers turn , the dice never spawn and the gamepiece continue to move (by 4) without the trigger which is the input.get touch ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that I could see wrong there already. First while the coroutine is running, it seems you are not preventing the update from running since play remains true. In TrapCheck, you call EndTurn which call GiveTurn and sets myTurn (true) and compTurn (false) booleans. But those two are reset in TrapCheck, myTurn is set back to false. You need to rethink the logic of your class.

A solution would be to use delegate. This would remove many of your boolean that you set and reset. Here is a basic idea:

```
Action currentUpdate;
bool playerTurn = true;
void Start(){
    SetTurn();
}
void Update(){
    if(currentUpdate != null)currentUpdate();
}
void SetTurn(){
    // Prepare initial setting for moving
    if(playerTurn == true){ currentUpdate = PlayerTurn; } 
    else{ currentUpdate = CompTurn; } 
    playerTurn = !playerTurn;
}

void PlayerTurn(){
    // Check input
    // Get dice value
    currentUpdate = Move;
}

void CompTurn(){
    // Get dice value
    currentUpdate = Move;
}

void Move(){
    if(position != target){

    }else{
        SetTurn();
    }
}
```

This is fairly simplified but once you get the thing about delegate (maybe you already know), this will make it all so much more flexible.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion , i dont know how to use action.. im just new in C#, but your explanation about my code help me a lot.. TY